# NSNotification listening

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nsnotification, addobserver

I have multiple instances of NSWindowController, who is registering for a notification to listen whenever edit happens.

Now when I edit something from one instance of windowcontroller, the notification gets posted and all the instances of that NSWindowcontroller listen to that notification,but I want only the instance which has updated its details to listen.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use NSNotificationCenter and pass type of NSWindowController so that particular instance get updated

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the documentation for `[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]` method for parameter `object`:

> The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is,
>   only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.
>   If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s
>   sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

So just pass `self` as object.
E.G.

Registering for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(someSelector:)
                                                 name:@"SomeNotification"
                                               object:self]; // <- SELF!!
```

Posting notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomeNotification"
                                                            object:self //<- SELF!!
                                                          userInfo:nil];
```